# 0xc000000f BCD error in windows 10... Nothings working

Tags: windows-10, boot, bcd

Its been a long night... I bought a new computer with no os. I was going to copy my copy of windows 10 pro to a 250gb ssd. While copying the power went out. This usually is just a minor annoyance but for some reason it must have went off at the exact wrong time and the hdd head just swiped something wrong... It started off with a windows that just said something along the lines of,

Windows had a error:

```
error code: 0xc000000f
Try to use a boot medium/recovery disk to fix it...
```

So i had a usb recovery tool and i thought it was just a simple bcd error.
I ran CHKDSK and it ran successfully rebooted into my os. I was so happy something finally worked. I rebooted for other reasons in the os, and then i got a different error. This time from my UEFI/BIOS saying

"insert a boot medium with a Operating System"

At this moment i knew something was wrong so i made a windows 10 recovery disk and booted into recovery mode, then proceeded to follow these tutorials or at least some like them
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508

http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/fix-0xc0000034-error-windows-10

These tutorials fall through all at the same place... When I run bootrec /rebuildbcd it can't find any windows operating systems.

I basically just asking for somebody to put me in the right direction. Thanks to everybody in advance!

EDIT: (after executing suggested bcdboot command)

Links to Pictures of errors:

Windows error display

[image]

GParted display of disk

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yrWayjQ.png]

Comment: No it is not, but that does help. Thanks to that post I now know that I have a BCD. I Just ran bcdedit /enum and it gave me the raw list, so it does exist... just doesn't work...

Comment: To recap, i just want to know how to delete/rename the existing bcd and create a new defualt one in its place

Answer (score 0):

When bootrec fails there is always **bcdboot.exe**!

bcdboot does less things than bootrec.exe but is [all you need to fix BCD](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html) on UEFI and BIOS firmware.

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s M:
```

c: is where Windows is, M: is active partition or ESP (change drive letters to reflect your concrete mappings).

The tools bootsect.exe and bcdboot.exe can fix all boot problems (you need of course either active partition for MBR booting or EFI System partition(ESP) for UEFI booting to be present on disk).

Note:

On UEFI firmware and GPT style disk MBR and Partition Boot Records(PBR) are not used for booting - firmware loads directly Windows boot manager. Be careful when booting Windows Recovery USB/DVD to select UEFI boot when fixing UEFI booting on hard disk!

EDIT:

OP reports new error after execution of bcdboot command. Error is:

```
“Windows failed to load because the kernel is missing or contains errors"

File: \windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
Error code: 0xc00000e9
```

Suggested solution:

```
chkdsk c: /F
```

where c: is Windows drive.

Then sfc command:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows
```

This repeats the steps suggested in: (solution to strange Windows boot problems)

[How to fix:
The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html)

Comment: I followed the tutorial and got a new error... 0xc00000e9

Comment: Update your computer info: 1) what style is disk - MBR or UEFI, post some text or graphic info on partitions(use diskpart or some other tool), specify which partition is Windows.

Comment: Please forgive me for the ignorance of the subject. I belive its a mbr style. Expect pictures within the hour of errors. In the mean time ill boot into ubuntu and show gparted. Thank you.

Comment: Please read article linked last for further details.

Comment: Alright.... I followed the article and everything seemed to work... 1 reboot. And I still got the error         “Windows failed to load because the kernel is missing or contains errors"

File: \windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
Error code: 0xc00000e9 I don't know if i missed something but this is getting old.

Comment: Did "sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows" run? (with your mappings) How come you run command, no errors(you say - seemed to work) and then again "ntoskrnl.exe" error ??? sfc is System File Check - if it runs it 100% checks os kernel ;)

Comment: sfc runs correctly for me but bcdboot results in `BFSVC Error: Could not open the BCD template store. Status = [c000000f]` :(

Comment: If BCD template is missing or cannot be read MS tools like bcdboot or bootrec cannot fix system BCD. Fix "BCD template" first!!! Get a "fresh" BCD template from any Windows distribution media (ISO, DVD, wim image).

Comment: It is impossible to fix all possible Windows boot errors in one answer ;) But if you fixed your booting, it would nice to let us know.